# Endofunctor as a presheaf

Tags: category-theory

This looks pretty obvious, but an endofunctor $F : Set \to Set$ seems to be a presheaf over $Set^{op}$.

Is there any useful fact that can be learnt from this view of endofunctors?

Comment: We usually only consider presheaves over small categories. $\mathbf{Set}$ is not small.

Comment: Perhaps one should restrict to $F$ preserving directed colimits, or equivalently to functors $F : \mathsf{FinSet} \to \mathsf{Set}$. This is related to combinatorial species.